# Error in Chrome while using FightinglayoutBugs

Tags: javascript

While trying to find out layout issues when a particular page is loaded in different browser using Selenium WebDriver and FightingLayoutBugs is used
But in Chrome, while page is loaded, certain runtime exception is arising.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to analyze https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1 -- com.googlecode.fightinglayoutbugs.AnimationDetectedException: This is strange: Found animated pixels, although
- all JavaScript animations have been stopped,
- all animated GIF images have been hidden,
- all elements potentially containing animation (like Java Applets, Flash Movies, videos, and iframes) are ignored.
- all CSS animations have been paused, and
- all CSS transitions have been disabled.
Analysis is stopped, so you don't get false alarms.

If you call FightingLayoutBugs.enableDebugMode() before you call FightingLayoutBugs.findLayoutBugsIn(...) you can get more information.
    at com.googlecode.fightinglayoutbugs.FightingLayoutBugs.findLayoutBugsIn(FightingLayoutBugs.java:226)
    at Fightpackage.Fight.f2(Fight.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: com.googlecode.fightinglayoutbugs.AnimationDetectedException: This is strange: Found animated pixels, although
- all JavaScript animations have been stopped,
- all animated GIF images have been hidden,
- all elements potentially containing animation (like Java Applets, Flash Movies, videos, and iframes) are ignored.
- all CSS animations have been paused, and
- all CSS transitions have been disabled.
Analysis is stopped, so you don't get false alarms.

    at com.googlecode.fightinglayoutbugs.AnimationAwareTextDetector.detectTextPixelsIn(AnimationAwareTextDetector.java:77)
    at com.googlecode.fightinglayoutbugs.WebPage.getTextPixels(WebPage.java:210)
    at com.googlecode.fightinglayoutbugs.DetectTextNearOrOverlappingHorizontalEdge.findLayoutBugsIn(DetectTextNearOrOverlappingHorizontalEdge.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.fightinglayoutbugs.FightingLayoutBugs.findLayoutBugsIn(FightingLayoutBugs.java:185)
    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score -1):

From the error message mentioned, it looks like you're trying to connect to **Google Account** with **Chrome**.
I believe the problem is the server at *accounts.google.com* is not available. 
The reason might be *DNS lookup* or simply DNS server is not responding, Usually it occurs because of several reasons, Please check below mentioned things hope it will help you to fix this issue.

1. Check *Firewall settings* at your node because some times Google chrome prevents accessing network.
2. Try *Re-starting Machine(HUB), Router* because an IP mismatch/misconfiguration can also be responsible for this.
3. Check *DNS* settings
4. If youre using *Proxy server* please recheck the proxy server settings, Make Sure 'Use a Proxy server for your LAN' is checked  if youre using proxy.